# From where can see how many spark job running in server?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, distributed-computing

I submitted spark job in linux server and can see in console and determine it is running or not.

But in case of production multiple spark job submiting and running on server,

So at that time from where I can see how many spark job running?

Comment: what is your resource/cluster manager ?

Comment: @mrsrinivas Spark jobs are running on cluster

Answer (score 3):

You can get list of running applications from command line (assuming that you are using yarn)

```
yarn application --list
```

[more](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html) about yarn command line operations

Answer (score 0):

Every SparkContext launches a web UI, by default on port 4040 on the host you submit your application. For more application monitoring details check this [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)